# Django redirect show all details

Tags: django

I have a newbie question. I am passing some values to the index template but via the /ideas/ url of the website.

This means, some of the data from the original index view does not show, as we're looking at a different view.

How can I achieve the same as the below, but redirecting back to the index & also passing the context in?

```
def ideas(request):
    idea = request.POST.get('ideasx')

    if idea == 'itsupport':
        skills = ['Computer Networking', 'sss']
    else:
        skills = 'sss'
    return render(request, 'index.html', {'skills':skills})
```

Comment: I know it doesn't help but if you wanna start with Django just follow some yt/online tutorial it will show you the basics because answers might overwhelm you. If you want my answer please state your problem more clearly - no idea what you mean in your problem but happy to help if you give some more info

Comment: A redirect will always trigger a GET request, and thus without payload.